# NpgSQL resources and references

Tags: c#, .net, npgsql

I have connected to my PostgreSQL database using .NET npgsql. I am programming in C#. Where can I find how to manipulate with this database using npgsql? Resources. Please don't send me http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html, because it is very un-detailed, making it unhelpful.

NgpSQL tutorial would be an ideal situation.

Answer (score 0):

As is clearly stated in the docs, Npgsql is a standard .NET driver (ADO.NET), so any .NET database tutorial out there would do. You may also have missed the link to the MSDN docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx